# Android SDK Manager not showing updates or new packages, only shows installed

Tags: android, xamarin

I've created a Xamarin Forms project on VS 2017. A co-worker opened the project and attempted to build but got the following error when building.

> Please open the Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of
>   'Android Support Repository' From the 'Extras' section, and then load
>   your solution.

When we tried to get the packages nothing was listed, except for the installed packages.

What I have tried so far:

- Setup proxy setting on both SDK manager and VS 2017
- Installed all VS updates
- Enabled force https. Still didn't work.
- SDK Manager log shows no errors.
- Verified I can go to both repositories from web browser. But I did notice that on Chrome I get a proxy message stating that I am be tracked on the site and to click continue or go back. This is

Worse thing is that my SDK Manager is doing the same thing now, which seems that it may be an IT issue. But, I'm trying to verify that it's an issue related to IT.

Do any of you have any other suggestions or ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: You could read [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91516/android-support-repository-error-xbd404), same error as your question.

Comment: @YorkShen I tried what the forum post stated to do but the same errors are present when building.

Comment: Your co-worker open the project on another computer? Where is your co-worker's SDK Location? Select `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Setting`, open the `Android SDK Manager` in this `Android SDK Location`, then update the Repository.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT No it looks to be an issue with the proxy that our internal IT group has setup. I'm able to run the project on a computer that isn't on the company domain and can even get all available update in SDK manager. But on our office computers, since they are on the domain and using proxy, we can't hit the google links and get the needed SDK tools. Thanks for your help, it's now up to our IT group to allow access to those links.